# jQuery val() not getting value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my code:

```
    jQuery('span.con').delegate('input#sdate', 'focus', function(e){

    try {
        var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
        rangeConv = new AnyTime.Converter({format: '%m-%d-%Y %k:%i'});
        fromDay = rangeConv.parse(jQuery(this).val()).getTime();
        dayLater = new Date(fromDay+oneDay);
        dayLater.setHours(0,0,0,0);

        jQuery(this). AnyTime_picker({
            askSecond: false,       
            format: '%m-%d-%Y %k:%i'
        }); 

    } catch(e){
        alert(jQuery.error);
        jQuery.error = console.error;

    }

    //jQuery('span.con input#sdate').val();
    alert(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

The alert() is showing a blank popup. Can some one guide me how can I get value of 'ITSELF' input box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have caught `e` but then tried to display something else.  Do this instead:

```
} catch(e){
        alert(e.message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here `jQuery(this)` refers to the span and not the input box , that's why its showing a blank alert. use the input box id to get the value .